# tweetinvi working on local host but throwing dll error on azure server

Tags: c#, .net, azure, dll, tweetinvi

The error below occurs when attempting to make an api request using tweetinvi running on an azure web role.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks,
>   Version=2.6.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried installing the nuget package for this dll, but then I get a compilation error (same type being declared in two places,) because apparently, `system.threading.tasks` in bundled inside of `mscorlib.dll`

.NET version: 4.5

tweetinvi version : v4.0.30319 strong name

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mentioned tweetinvi version is the Runtime Version. I do a demo using [TweetinviAPI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetinviAPI/1.3.0-alpha). It works correctly on my side. If it is possible, please have a try to redeploy it again or create new cloudservie to test it again..

The following is my detail steps:

1.Create cloudservive project and with WebRole.

2.Reference the tweetinvi with Nuget

[image]

3.Create Tweetinvi application (https://apps.twitter.com/) and get the **Consumer Key**,**Consumer Secret**, **Access Token**,  **Access Token Secret**

[image]
4.Add the following code in the HomeController About() to test it.

```
  Auth.SetUserCredentials(string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string userAccessToken, string userAccessSecret);

            // Publish the Tweet "Hello Tweetinvi" on your Timeline
            Tweet.PublishTweet("Hello Tweetinvi! ");
```

5.Publish the cloudservice to Azure and visit(http://xxxxx.cloudapp.net/Home/About) get the test result.

6.Check from twitter, it works correctly

[image]